# How to Compile Agda Hello World on Nixos?

Tags: agda, nixos

On nixos, I am trying to compile the hello world example listed in the [agda documentation](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0.1/getting-started/hello-world.html).

In my working directory, I have the following:

The hello-world agda program, `hello-world.agda`:

```
module hello-world where

open import IO

main = run (putStrLn "Hello, World!")
```

A nix shell file, `shell.nix`:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { } }:
with pkgs;
mkShell {
  buildInputs = [
    (agda.withPackages (ps: [
      ps.standard-library
    ]))
  ];
}
```

To enter a shell with the `standard-library` dependency available, I ran `$ nix-shell shell.nix`.

Then, trying to compile the program, I ran `$ agda --compile hello-world.agda`, as advised by the linked agda hello world documentation.

But that gave me the following error:

```
$ agda --compile hello-world.agda
Checking hello-world (/home/matthew/backup/projects/agda-math/hello-world.agda).
/home/matthew/backup/projects/agda-math/hello-world.agda:3,1-15
Failed to find source of module IO in any of the following
locations:
  /home/matthew/backup/projects/agda-math/IO.agda
  /home/matthew/backup/projects/agda-math/IO.lagda
  /nix/store/7pg293b76ppv2rw2saf5lcbckn6kdy7z-Agda-2.6.2.2-data/share/ghc-9.0.2/x86_64-linux-ghc-9.0.2/Agda-2.6.2.2/lib/prim/IO.agda
  /nix/store/7pg293b76ppv2rw2saf5lcbckn6kdy7z-Agda-2.6.2.2-data/share/ghc-9.0.2/x86_64-linux-ghc-9.0.2/Agda-2.6.2.2/lib/prim/IO.lagda
when scope checking the declaration
  open import IO
```

It seems it should be finding the standard library, since I'm running from the nix-shell with agda's standard-library specified, but that error on `open import IO` looks like the standard library is somehow still not found.

Any idea what the problem is likely to be?
Or what else I can do to get agda working on nixos?

Comment: What's the output of `which agda`?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a `defaults` file in `AGDA_DIR` (which typically refers to `~/.agda/` unless overwritten through environment variable) with the libraries you want to make available to your program:

```
echo standard-library >> ~/.agda/defaults
```

which should make the compiler automatically load the standard library.

Alternatively, you can pass them in on the command-line:

```
agda -l standard-library
```

or use a project-local `.agda-lib` file as follows:

```
name: my-libary
depend: standard-library
include: -- Optionally specify include paths
```

You should not need to specify the include paths with Nix, but in case you do, you can use the `-i` command line flag or add the path to the standard-library.agda-lib file in `~/.agda/libraries`.